# Pull request is adding other peoples work in bitbucket when working off old branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

How do I pull in changes from master to an old branch that is weeks old? Whenever I checkout my old branch to work on feedback, commit my code and create a pull request in bitbucket, it will add in other peoples work on my branch because it is not up to date. The way I have worked around this is to just create a new branch off master but is there a way to just use the old branch? I am using terminal as my CLI. Thank you in advance.

I have gone back to the master branch and did git pull.
Checked out my old branch and from there did git config pull.rebase true.

Comment: When you say the Pull Request "will add in other peoples work", do you mean it's showing extra commits that you did not make? If yes: Can you think of a reason why those extra commits are on your branch but not on `master`? (Maybe they are similar to other commits on `master` but have different commit IDs?) Did you branch off of something other than `master` when you started your old branch? Or was `master` re-written in the last few weeks?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the upstream branch is named `master` on the remote `origin` and your old branch is `oldbranch`, you can do something like this:

```bash
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout oldbranch
$ git rebase origin/master
```

Note if there are textual conflicts between changes on `oldbranch` and new changes on master, you'll be prompted to resolve those during the rebase (and you can use `git status` for instructions on "what do to next" during that process).